# Combine results with different veracity

Tags: time-series, probability

I have 3 neural networks processing 3 different vectors of values. Each NN processes a sample of it's vector and gives binary result (y/n) that is correct with given probability. All 3 NNs give answer to the same question. The task is to combine this results into single one (y/n) and figure out probability that it is correct.

What methods can you suggest for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173329/combine-results-with-different-veracity) one guy helped me to find solution using different measurement method.